# accessing gestures with app running in background in android

Tags: java, android, gesture

is there a way of having an app running in the background access gestures when there is nothing (visibly) running on the phone. for example I would like to be able to create an app which runs in the background and detects a pinch gesture and fire off a custom method when no app is currently open in the foreground. is this possible?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. You'd need some kind of UI displayed on the main thread to pick up these gestures. A touch cannot be grabbed by a background service.

Comment: is it possible to have a transparent "overlay" as a ui that still allows the phones normal functionality to continue?...or a small icon displayed taking up a minimal portion of the screen which still catches gestures across the full screen?

Comment: Hmm, you could probably use a framelayout and set background to transparent but I don't know if that would work the way you want. Try it out.